# Access app_metadata from Auth0 Lock

Tags: javascript, authentication, auth0, auth0-lock

I am trying to access the `app_metadata` from Auth0 and I am using the Lock client. I have found the [custom claims](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/adoption/scope-custom-claims) and created the rule that they show, but now I have no idea how actually use that data. Here is the function that handles all my authentication:

```
setSession(authResult) {
    if (authResult && authResult.accessToken && authResult.idToken) {
        this.lock.getUserInfo(authResult.accessToken, function(err, profile) {
            if (err) {
                return;
            }

            localStorage.setItem("access_token", authResult.accessToken);
            localStorage.setItem("id_token", authResult.idToken);
            localStorage.setItem("expires_at", JSON.stringify((authResult.expiresIn * 1000) + new Date().getTime()));
            localStorage.setItem("profile", JSON.stringify(profile));

            history.replace("/home");
        });
    }
}
```

I would expect to just be able to get the `app_metadata` from the profile after including that, but this does not appear to be the case. Am I doing anything wrong or am I forgetting something?

**EDIT 1:** Here is the rule that I have currently.

```
function (user, context, callback) {
   const namespace = "https://alexkrantz.com";
   context.accessToken[namespace + "user_metadata"] = user.user_metadata;
   context.accessToken[namespace + "app_metadata"] = user.app_metadata;
   callback(null, user, context);
}
```

Comment: Can you post the exact rule you made? The posted example modifies the `idToken`, you're accessing the `accessToken` here.

Comment: @Joris I've added what I have currently

Comment: Profile is not the same as your `accessToken`. If you [decode][https://github.com/auth0/jwt-decode] the `accessToken`, you'll find your custom fields in there. It might be that there is an easier solution, but I'm not sure.

Also, your `namespace` should end in a `/`.

Comment: That worked thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can make a request and get all the user data from the management API and there you will find the user_metadata and the app_metadata, this way

```
const res = await fetch(`${process.env.AUTH0_ISSUER}/api/v2/users/${user.id}`,{
          method:'GET',
          headers: {authorization: 'Bearer management_api_token'},
        })
```

here you will find more in documentation
https://auth0.com/docs/manage-users/user-accounts/manage-users-using-the-management-api
https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2#!/Users/get_users_by_id